# What does SaveAll do in the RStudio file menu?

Tags: environment-variables, save, rstudio

Periodically and sometimes unexpectedly, our company resets or restarts our computers.
Sometimes this might happen before I am around to save my current Rstudio session.

I know that I can save my scripts and files with control-S, and I know that I *can* save my environment variables with save.image().  When I exit, Rstudio does this automatically (or gives me the option).

I would like to be able to do this from my Rstudio session without leaving Rstudio and without having to enter specific commands?

It doesn't look like "Save All" from the File menu does this.  I guess that it just saves all open files which haven't been saved since the last change.

In the worst case, you can save your environment objects and command history with:

save.image();  savehistory()

(btw, I definitely understand the philosophy of reproducible data... making sure that you save your code, but sometimes you are in the middle of something and don't get a chance to put the code into your script...)

File -> Save All

.RData & .Rhistory file timestamps do not get updated.